# Drupal site requires a higher memory limit after migration? Why?

Tags: php, linux, apache, drupal

We have a website which had a previous memory limit of 12 MB (12 MB in php.ini, and 16 MB in settings.php) and worked previously.

After moving to a new server it started giving memory limit errors and displaying half-blank screen.

We increaded the limit in both files (php.ini and settings.php) and now it works, but I dont understand how is it possible that now it needs a considerably larger amount of memory (it used to work with 12 MB, now it cont work with less than 20 MB).

Comment: Same verisons of PHP? Same modules installed?

Comment: Please add the Apache and PHP versions of the old and new servers. Was there a memcache or similar on the old server?

Comment: Maybe you went from a 32-bits to a 64-bits operating system?

Comment: @edwin: yeah, I think its probably that, I am not sure if the old server was 32 or 64 bit, but the new one is definetely 64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you did not change the OS in the process. Moving from Windows to Linux or vice versa is quite likely to change resource usage.

And this is a long shot, but perhaps you moved from a 32-bit system to a 64-bit one? This would slightly increase memory usage as addresses (pointers) are twice as large on 64-bit architectures, and code with lots of small objects uses plenty of pointers.

On the whole though, we can't tell you much without seeing what changed about the system.

Answer (score 1):

12 is too low, if you don't use only drupal as it is. Higher is recommend, than more modules you will install, usually 96MB is enough with image processing...

Answer (score 0):

12 MB is really very low. I would tend to ignore it and go on.

Ideas what could have changed, though:

- The old server could have had modules installed that reduced memory usage, e.g. `memcache`
- The new server may have to rely on `GD` library for image processing, while the old server maybe had `ImageMagick` (which is an external tool and doesn't count towards the memory limit)